# How to find different data under same year in acess

Tags: ms-access

I have made a database.But i am facing problem.

For example i have data for students like below:

```
No.     name  department   Passing year  
 1       X    economics     2002
 2       Y    history       2000 
 3       Z    Math          2002
```

When i enter `passing year 2002` in the combo box search then it shows `only one result` but i want to display all the results those passing year is 2002.How can i do this?I am using Microsoft 2007.

Access experts need your help.

Comment: Re: "When i enter passing year 2002 then it shows only one result" - Enter it *where*?

Comment: When i enter passing year 2002 in the combo box search then it shows only one result.

Comment: ^ That.  Is.  Classic.

Answer (score 1):

I can't even guess at what exactly is going on, based on what you've stated, but I **can** tell you how to get the results you're searching for.

1) Set up a new form.  Call it subfrmPassingYear.  For the RecordSource of the form, set it equal to the name of the table that the student info is in.  For our purposes, going forward I'm going to refer to it as tblStudents.

2) In the Default View property of this form, you will either need to change it to Continuous Form or Datasheet.  It will default to Single Form, which is a bad choice here.

3) Set up another new form.  Call it frmPassingYear.

4) Add a new Subform to frmPassingYear.  It's an object, and should be in the same toolbox as the textbox, label, combo and all those other objects.  It **should** automatically launch the Wizard, and you would choose "Existing Form" and select subfrmPassingYear from the list.  If the Wizard doesn't launch, just set the Source Object property of the subform to subfrmPassingYear.

5) Add a new combo to frmPassingYear.  Call it cboPassingYear.  As its RecordSource, set it to "SELECT DISTINCT [Passing Year] FROM tblStudents ORDER BY [Passing Year] ASC".

6) In the AfterUpdate event of cboPassingYear, put this statement:

```
Dim sSQL as String

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE [Passing Year] = " & Trim(Me!cboPassingYear.Text) & ""
Forms!frmPassingYear.subfrmPassingYear.Form.RecordSource = sSQL
```

Run frmPassingYear, select a passing year from the combo and the subform should populate with records only from that year.  If your year is stored as TEXT instead of INTEGER, you'll need to add single quotes to the SQL string.